# Teamcity - How to trigger scheduled builds for all feature branchs?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I have some branches that I use for release `release/vX.x.xx`.

I want to always run a build for the latest change on any of this branches (the last one modified, I don't care for the other ones) as a scheduled nightly build.

- I configured the VCS root to aim to `refs/heads/master` (the release branch always change so I can't aim to that one as the default)
- branch specification: `+:refs/heads/(release/*)`
- In the triggers, I set a *Schedule Trigger* with *Additional Options > Trigger Build in Branches* set to `+:refs/heads/release/*`.
- I also tried to set *Triggering Conditions > Edit Trigger Rules* to `+:refs/heads/(release/*)`

Although I did all this, and I see the **x pending** in the Build configuration tab, when the scheduled time arrives, it doesn't build any branch.

How can I set it up so it will always build the latest change on any branch that matches the pattern in my scheduled trigger?

I'm using **TeamCity 2019.2.2**

Comment: Have you added brackets () everywhere in branch specification ? Try to remove that from everywhere, just write +:refs/heads/release/*

Comment: I already tried with that and it didn't work

Comment: VCS root -> branch specification and schedule trigger is enough settings, have you tried without additional option in scheduled trigger ?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid I had the same result

Comment: Does it work if you write a branch name without wildcards? e.g., +:refs/heads/release/v42.0.1. I've configured triggers for things like +:refs/heads/12.* and it worked as expected, so it could be something basic that is missing in your configuration.